# How to redirect a URL to a custom IP address?

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I have an Ubuntu machine that I'm using as my home Internet router.  It uses a USB mobile broadband modem as its Internet connection, and shares this with another router (via the router's "Internet" port) which I use as my LAN.

How do I redirect requests from within my LAN for a given URL to a custom IP address (ex have google.com redirect to x.x.x.x)?

Comment: Using DNS would be the way to do this, but as I have not successfully set up `bind9` DNS, I am not providing this information as an answer.

Comment: Ugh, me neither... guess I can try bind9 again :)

Comment: Okay, I've got bind9 setup and working (maybe?), how do I make a rule to redirect the url?

Comment: as i've said, i havent ever configured `bind9` correctly, so I can't help you unfortunately.  You might wait for someone else to come around

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to come about this is properly installing `dnsmasq` (which is a DNS cacheing server) then in the folder `/etc/dnsmasq.d` add a file for each domain you want to redirect.

For instance this is the contents of `/etc/dnsmasq.d/hotmail.com` on my system:

```
address=/hotmail.com/127.0.0.1
address=/www.hotmail.com/127.0.0.1
```

If I then ask the DNS server for the IP of hotmail.com i get 127.0.0.1 like this:

```
llp@cerberus:~$ nslookup hotmail.com
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Name:   hotmail.com
Address: 127.0.0.1

llp@cerberus:~$
```

There are a bit more options you can set, they can all be found described in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it could be done!  Just a note, don't install dnsmasq!  Ubuntu comes with dnsmasq-base, which provides the same functionality, I think.  Config file is `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, just add `address=` for each entry, as above.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but the problem is I'm behind a proxy. This solution is not working for me.

Comment: did you try cname?

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple IPs?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/710621/something-is-listening-on-port-53