# DNS Server - Help with Redirect traffic of a specific url to a Local IP address

Tags: dns, redirect

I've been working on this problem for the past week and still can't solve it.

I want to setup something probably a CNAME record or an A record that will help me with redirecting traffic from an external url to an internal ip address.

I want all request for the following url: vc.example.com to be forwarded to a local IP address (10.8.8.5). If the request for anything else that has the same domain, it will still go externally like: web.example.com.

Is this possible? Any assistance is appreciated.

Alee6179

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/53523/how-to-redirect-a-url-to-a-custom-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Askubuntu

It's very common thing and widely applied by system administrators.
You need to add your  external router/Gateway ip in your Cname and other records. You can edit your name records using  domain name provider. This will redirect users to your network's router/gateway from outside.  At your side You need to configure router (depends on your router/gateway) port forwarding  80 port to local your server's 80 port. Now users will be directly redirected to your local server.

Comment: Here is my config file:  @       IN      SOA     tahomafaculty.com. root.tahomafaculty.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.tahomafaculty.com.
@       IN      A       10.8.8.5
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
ns      IN      A       10.8.8.5

vc      IN      A       10.8.8.1
vc.summitps.org.        IN      CNAME   vc.tahomafaculty.com.

Comment: Here is my config file:  
@       IN      SOA     test.com. root.test.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.test.com.
@       IN      A       10.8.8.5
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
ns      IN      A       10.8.8.5

vc      IN      A       10.8.8.1
vc.example.com.        IN      CNAME   vc.test.com.