# Something is listening on port 53

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, netstat

I want to set up `bind9`, but something is listening on port 53. It's local address is ubuntu.ubuntu-do:domain. How to disable it, so it wouldn't listen anymore? I think it is `dnsmasq`, but still I don't know hot to disable it.

Answer (score 7):

Port 53 is reserved for the Domain Name System (DNS).

In your case it is the DNS cacher `dnsmasq` of the package `dnsmasq-base`. This *pre-installed* package is a *dependency* of `network-manager`, the network manager of your desktop environment (e.g. Unity, GNOME, …).

For this reason, don't uninstall the package `dnsmasq-base` and/or disable the service. Install `bind9` and all is fine

```
sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Now you should see something like this, `bind9` (`named`) is also running on port 53:

```
% sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ":53 "
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.131:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8921/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8921/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1223/dnsmasq    
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      8921/named      
udp        0      0 192.168.2.131:53        0.0.0.0:*                           8921/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           8921/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1223/dnsmasq    
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                8921/named
```

---

Use the command

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

to show the **p**orts and **l**istening processes for **u**dp and **t**cp. For DNS it's usually UDP.

Use

```
ps -p PID -o comm=
```

to show the command name for the given process id (PID).

Comment: everything would be cool, except that when I type: "sudo service dnsmasq disable" it says that that service is not recognized, when i type "sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq" it says no program installed, but when I type "sudo netstat -tulpn" it says the port 53 is used by dnsmasq. Why?

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not explain how to disable dnsmasq. I'd like to disable it because I want to run dnsmasq from a docker container instead.