# How to set up an internal-only domain on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dns, netplan

I am trying to set up a domain in my LAN, so that all my devices, which are attached to it, can access anything `*.base.home` (e.g. `gitlab.base.home`, `nexus.base.home`, `che-che.base.home`) and get redirected to a particular IP (and port?) on my network.

I currently have e.g. `https://base:12081` as my nexus server. How would I go about turning it into `https://nexus.base.home` in such a way, that it'd be known under this domain and subdomain in my LAN?

I have an **Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS** server, which is always on and attached to my router. At the current moment the server gets its IPs via DHCP, but my router ensures, that my server always gets the same IP. I could move the server and force a static IP, though - if it was necessary.
Is it okay for my server to be a DNS controller along with serving various docker containers etc.?

I also read various tutorials on using `bind9` and `netplan`, but they are always using some `10...`-IPs and I am not sure which ones I am supposed to use and how reverse zone files have to be written to work.

**Could someone point me in the right direction and tell me how to go about this?**

If it matters: my internal IPs - currently - start with `192.168.178.*` and I am not using ipv6.

**Note:** I do not own any external domain, that I'd like to use. I just want this to work at home so that I can try and run Eclipse Che 7+ on minikube as well as easily access gitlab, nexus, gitlab-pages and various projects using subdomains.

Edit: perhaps if I follow [How to redirect a URL to a custom IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53523/how-to-redirect-a-url-to-a-custom-ip-address), I could end up doing just exactly what I'd like (also if I force my router to use the same computer as a DNS controller and forward anything it cannot map on its own to a `1.1.1.1` or the likes)?

Comment: I see nobody gave you an answer. Are you familiar with .local? For example, if I want to SSH into this computer (from another), I use `ssh kgiii-desktop.local`. If I want to SSH into my laptop, it's `sudo kgiii-lmde.local` (as it runs LMDE). Your hostname + .local works for all that stuff. Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you really need a better wheel. Yes, it even works for servers. I could start up a server and connect with https://kgiii-desktop.local just fine.

Comment: @KGIII so... Do I understand correctly: the `local` domain exists and I can connect from one `local` device within the network to another (say `devpc.local` to `base.local`) without having to set up anything? My core problem is a bit different though: I do not know how to make Subdomains (such as `pages.base.local` or `nexus.base.local`) accessible from my other network devices... Which is why I thought I need a local domain first in order to be able to define all sorts of subdomains. I need this especially for Eclipse Che, but also other Intranet-based software.

Comment: Yeah, the .local exists. I'm connected to kgiii-lmde.local right now. As for "subdomains", I'm not too sure - but different users *should* mean different host names. So a user named foo.kgiii-lmde *may* work. I have never tested this and I'm not even 100% sure that you can use a period in the username. I'd just avoid the complexity and stick with the hostname.local route. If you have another computer on your network try `ping user_name.local` to see if in action. Also, I'm not sure why I typed 'sudo' in the previous comment. I assume wine was a factor.

Comment: Also, on the off-chance that the username isn't the hostname, you can run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname` to find the hostname. Then that's what you put in front of .local to access it without even knowing the IP address.

Comment: @KGIII thanks - `ping base.local` worked (it's my server in the network). The subdomains aren't exactly users, they are sort-of "links" to certain parts of the network (see https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/subdomain/). Actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078840/is-this-possible-to-create-subdomains-on-local-server seems to explain if / how to create a subdomain on local - which would be exactly what I'd do (I do not necessarily need a whole new domain or something). Thanks for the hints! I suppose I'll post my findings as an answer later - if it works out.

Comment: LOL I own a small hosting company, so know what subdomains are - but in your case (using .local) I'm not sure if you'll need to set them as users or not. I've never needed to dig that deep, as my local needs aren't very complicated. The other answer looks fairly promising. I may have to try the hosts solution here, just to test it out. And, please do post an answer. It may only help a few people, but those few people will be grateful.

Comment: @KGIII first I want to apologize for being rude without knowing - sorry. I figured out, that I could have subdomains if I set them up in the corresponding `hosts` file. However: keeping them all in sync is very difficult, so I suppose I might want to look into using e.g. apache on every subdomain and redirecting to the corresponding service perhaps - or something among those lines. I do not want to take care of every `hosts` file on every computer.. I thought that's what DNS is for?

Comment: It's all good. I'd imagine the hosts would be fairly trivial to maintain - once configured.